# Are there Func objects with more than 4 parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx) that `Func<(Of <(T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>)>) Delegate` was the last `Func` in the namespace. What do you do if you need more than 4 parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create your own `Func` delegates, or you could wait for .NET 4 to arrive (it includes built-in [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862(VS.100).aspx) and [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402872(VS.100).aspx) delegates with up to sixteen parameters).

As others have mentioned, if you find yourself needing a delegate that takes this many parameters then maybe it's time to think about some sort of refactoring.

```
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>
    (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5);

public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult>
    (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6);

public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult>
    (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7);

public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult>
    (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8);

// etc
```

Comment: .Net 4 will allow an unlimited number? By the way, can you post an example for the `Func` delegates you're talking about?

Comment: No, not an illimited number. You can have up to 16 parameters

Comment: Refactoring? Nah, too early. Even `String.Compare` takes in 7 parameters.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net 4, there's overloads till 17 (give or take) parameters.

Personally, I think that's nuts. If you need more than 4 parameters, then it's time to create a new class that has all the parameters you need as properties.

Comment: I find it a little ridiculous that you consider that to be "nuts". Even one of the most fundamental operations, `Array.Copy` has 5 parameters, as does `String.Compare` (**7** parameters) and in general lots of functions that have item/offset/count inputs and such.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parameter object, perhaps?

The refactor catalog has a [good description.](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: The must read book __CODE complete__ recommends up to 7 parameters. :-)

Comment: I think Steve McConnell must have had a very large monitor to read the method signatures ;) Agree wholeheartedly RE: Must Read.